# Firefox: why does <input type="slider"> retain its slider position after a reload (F5) of the page?

Tags: html

In a HTML page, I have a slider like so:

```
<input type="range" min="20" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="on_input(this.value);">
```

When I first open the page, the slider positions itself, as expected, on position 25.

Now, I slide the slider to another position and reload (F5) the page. In Firefox, the position is then not changed. Chrome however changes the slider to its original position (25).

I expected Firefox to behave as Chrome.

Is there an easy, non javascript trick, to make Firefox reposition the slider after reloading the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `autocomplete="off"` as another attribute.  Along with helping a user fill out a form the first time, it also avoids preserving values on page reload (at least for other input types).  Both scenarios are handled by form autocompletion.